# Use part of filename in powershell

Tags: powershell, filenames

I use this command:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test\AB*.zip | 
% {
    & "C:\test\7z.exe" "x" "-y" $_.fullname "-oC:\test\AB\"
}
```

I want to save in location which would be filename -2 symbols.
Have any tips?

Thanks

Comment: This question is unclear - do you want to remove the extension or something? What does `filename -2 symbols` mean?

Comment: I want to us filename without extension like "AB20140331.zip" unzip to path "...\AB201403\" without 2 last symbols. Sorry.

Comment: You can get the filename without extension with `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)` [(docs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx). However, I still don't understand what "path without last 2 symbols` means - what is a symbol?

Comment: I want to name folder by filename, but shorter. Script should take basename of file and shorten it. "123456.zip" unzips to direcotry names "1234"

Comment: @WhiteHorse What if you got two Zip files: AB12345 and AB12354. Both would end up as AB123. Is that what you'd like?

Comment: Yes. Both of them would unzip in same location, named AB123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way (not tested)

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test\AB*.zip | 
 % {
     $to  = $_.fullname.length - 2
     $path = $_.fullname.substring( 0, $to)
     & "C:\test\7z.exe" "x" "-y" $_.fullname "-o$path"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test\AB*.zip | % {
    $output = $_.fullname -replace '\w{2}$', '\'
    & "C:\test\7z.exe" "x" "-y" $_.fullname "-o$output"
}
```